# There are 12 students. The student forms 6 groups to do a project. Each week, the students can form the group as the wish. Prove the following.

Tags: combinatorics, fubini-tonelli-theorems

The full question is,
There are 12 students in Mr. Fat's combinatorics
class. At the beginning of each week, Mr. Fat assigns a project to
his students. The students form six groups. Each group works on
the project independently and submits the work at the end of the
week. Each week, the students can form the groups as they wish.
Prove that, regardless of the way the students choose their partners,
there are always two students such that there are at least five other
students who have all worked with both of them or have worked with
neither of them. (A student cannot work by himself.)

The question is from the book "A Path to combinatorics." The Solution is as follows,

This problem investigates the working partnership
between a student and a pair of students. Thus, we let A =
${s_1, s_2, ... , s_{12}}$ denote the set of all students, and let B = $\{(s_i, s_j) | 1 <= i < j <= 12\}$ denote the set of all pairs of students. Then
|B| = 66. We say that $s_i$ and $(s_j, s_k)$ are connected if $(s_i, s_j)$,
and $s_k$ are distinct and $s_i$ has worked with exactly one of $s_j$ and $s_k$.
Let, S = {$[s_i,(s_j, s_k)] | s_i$ and $(s_j,s_k)$ are connected }
Now we prove the desired result. We approach indirectly by assuming
that the statement is not true, that is, **that at some time, every pair
$(s_i,s_k)$ is connected to at least six students, or | S(*,$(s_j,s_k)$)| >= 6.**
Consequently, we have
|S|= sum(|S(*,$(s_j,s_k)$)|) $>= 6  \times |B| = 396$.
On the other hand, if $s_i$ has worked with $d$ partners, then $s_i$ is connected to $d(11 - d)$ pairs of students (because we have d ways to choose one of his previous partners and $11 - d$ ways to choose a student who has not worked with him). For integers $0 <= d <= 11$, the maximum value of $d(11 - d)$ is $30$, obtained when $d = 5$ or $6$. Hence |S($s_i$, *)| $<= 30$, implying that
|S| = sum(|S($s_i$, *)|) $<= 30 \times |A| = 360$
We obtain $396 <=$ |S| $<= 360$, which is impossible. Thus, our
assumption was wrong and the problem statement is true.

I don't understand how is the negation of the problem statement, the one stated in the solution(The **bold** statement).

Answer (score 0):

> Prove that, regardless of the way the students choose their partners,
> there are always two students such that there are at least five other
> students who have all worked with both of them or have worked with
> neither of them.

First, it's important to understand that if a student has "worked with both of them" or "neither of them" (them being students in a pair) is the same as saying that the student is not connected to the pair.

Now, there are a total of $12$ students. If we remove the $2$ students $(s_j, s_k)$ being considered, there are $10$ remaining. Of these ten, there must be at least five other students who are *not* connected to those two students. That leaves us with only $10- 5 = 5$ other students. Meaning the pair $(s_j, s_k)$ can be connected to a maximum of $5$ students.

Again, the question states - there must always be two students or one pair  in B such that the pair is *not* connected to at least five students. In other words, there must always be one pair that is connected to a maximum of five students.

**What's the negation of this?**

At some time, there is not a single pair in B that is connected to a maximum of five students. In other words, every pair in B is connected to at least $6$ students.